# How can I store data into the Facebook user's account?

Tags: facebook, account

I'm developing a PHP/Javascript application integrated with Facebook.

When a user accepts to share his information with my application, I need to store some small data about this user, for a future purpose.
So, yes, I can use a simple MySql on my server... but there are some information I'd like to store into my MySql server, and others information I'd like to store (in "some way"...) into the user's Fb account (in other word, into the Facebook's database).

Maybe, I can store this data as a "Note" message or something, but in this case, the user must share his Note messages with my application, and I don't want this.

There is any way to do that?

thank you very much, any suggest is appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you Vijay for your help. I'd like to add data to the user's account in facebook only for privacy & security purpose... because I think there is no best place to store the data.
Maybe I'm just a little bit paranoid :-) 'cause my application is just a little game, and there is no big privacy issue, but I'd like to store the data in a safe place. I'm not sure a MySql database in a big hosting farm would be a safe place, so I'm looking for a different technical solution. Thank you.

Comment: Facebook allows us to use its basic functionality which allows us to use them to build a social centric application/service.. You can't add data to the facebook database from your application (and that too a custom field/data). Its a worst design to think about adding content to fb db.. As you said in your post MySql is the best option from your application side..

Comment: @vijay Thank you Vijay for your help. I'd like to add data to the user's account in facebook only for privacy & security purpose... because I think there is no best place to store the data. Maybe I'm just a little bit paranoid :-) 'cause my application is just a little game, and there is no big privacy issue, but I'd like to store the data in a safe place. I'm not sure a MySql database in a big hosting farm would be a safe place, so I'm looking for a different technical solution. Thank you.

Comment: what kind of data are you storing? If you only need it temporarily and insecurely, you could just use a cookie, but the answer to this really depends on what it is you are saving. I certainly wouldn't consider a facebook user's notes to be more secure than a database on your server though!

Comment: @Abby I need to store data about the game I'm developing, such as game stragies and stuffs. These information could be shared with the friends, but should not shared with the world. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your app can write posts on a users wall and things like that, but you can't just randomly store data on their facebook account.

Why are you distrusting of MySQL?  Setup strong credentials, and lock it down correctly and you should be fine.  Make sure you go with a reputable hosting company as well.

Comment: Thank you Jack. I'm a little bit paranoid :-) ...but I think a MySql server is a not very trusted place for store important data, because we can't know the real security setup of the hosting company. For example, they backup our dbfiles or move it in another server. I don't know, maybe I'm a very paranoid programmer :-)